# Borel Cantelli Lemma Lim-sup Question

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am stuck on this one step in the proof of the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

1. We have infinite $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ where the sum of their probabilities is finite. (convergence)
2. Let $B$ be the event that infinitely many of the events $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ occur.
3. Let $B_n=\cup_{k\ge n}^\infty A_k$.
4. $B$ occurs if and only if $B_n$ occurs for all $n$, so $B=\cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{k\ge n}^\infty A_k$. (lim sup)
5. etc

How in the world does (4) work??

Going up to for example 3 events, we have $(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3) \cap (A_2\cup A_3) \cap A_3=A_3$, no? Since the sequence of $B_k$ is decreasing, and since $A_n$ terms approach $\varnothing$ as required by convergence, then $B=\varnothing$ -- quite the opposite of infinitely many events. But as far as I'm aware, this isn't supposed to be a proof by contradiction.

Clarification: I'm following an existing proof not trying to do it myself.

Comment: If you only have assumptions on probabilities, then there's no way to conclude anything is the empty event (how do you tell apart $\emptyset$ from any other event $C$ such that $P(C)=0$?)  You may want to try to rewrite your thoughts without referencing the empty set/event.  E.g. the most obvious change might be to note $P(A_n)\to 0$, which is true, but woefully insufficient to conclude $P(B)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counter example for the statement

> ... and  since $A_n$ terms approach $\varnothing$ as required by convergence, then $B = \varnothing$

We consider a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ (i.e. Lebesgue measure on this set), and say
$$
A_i = \left[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^n}\right] = \left\{ x: \left|x - \frac{1}{2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}\right\},
$$
then by simple calculation, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = 2 < \infty
$$
which satisfies the condition of Borel-Caltelli lemma.

And then we calculate $B$:

On the one hand, from the definition, $B$ means "infinitely many of events in $\{A_n\}$ happens, which means $x\in B$ satisfies: for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\left|x - \frac{1}{2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2^n},
$$
the only real number $x$ satisfying above condition is $1/2$, so
$$
B = \{1/2\}.
$$

On the other hand, according to the formula in step 4, we have
$$B=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k \geq n}^{\infty} A_k,$$
and firstly, it is not hard to verify that
$$
B_n = \cup_{k \geq n}^{\infty} A_k = A_n,
$$
(this is true only for this specific example!) and therefore
$$
B = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n  = \{1/2\}
$$
from a direct calculation.

In conclusion, with both definitions, we can find that $B = \{1/2\}$. This means that the statement that $B = \varnothing$ is not correct. On the other hand, the Borel-Cantelli lemma predicts that $P(B)=0$, and in fact this is correct since finite sets in $[0,1]$ have zero Lebesgue measure.

It is often advantageous to look for counterexamples when learning analysis.

Comment: Thank you, now I know there are non-null sets with zero probability. I was stuck in finite events before this example. However I'm still a bit unsure on the definition of $B$. The "event that infinitely many of the events $A_n$ occur" could be defined more simply as $\cap_n^\infty A_n$. In that sense is the use of $\cap\cup A_n$ just an artifice of the proof, or is there something deeper I'm missing?

Comment: And would this limsup definition not fail if $A_{n+1} \nsubseteq A_n$ (opposite to the example above)?

Comment: @helixer $\cup_{n}^{\infty} A_n$ means "every $A_k$ ($k\geq n$) happens. "Happening infinitely many times" is much looser than this. Consider "for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $A_{k^2}$", happens, this is also satisfies "infinitely many of $A_n$'s are happening", but it does not include $\cup_n^\infty A_n$ for any $n$, And the "limsup" you mentioned is nothing but the union of a family of sets, which can be defined for any family of sets.

Comment: Thanks. I hope you meant $\cap_n^\infty$ instead of union since union seems to me like "every $A_k, k>n$ *can* happen" rather than "every one *does* happen"... Still, another helpful comment about infinities. And I take back my second comment, which was based on a dumb counterexample of disjoint $A_k$ (infinite of those cannot occur by definition so obviously $B$ will reflect that). I was just following some probability text for review; didn't think I signed up for analysis 0_0.